# Changing Fields in AWK

Tags: awk

Basicall this is what I need to do in awk:
**

```
# Get fields 10, 11 & 12 from a record and check whether 10 = "No Name" & if 11=12
# if 11=12 then blank 11. Also blank anything with "No Name"...
```

**

My input is something like this:

```
UPRN|ENDDATE|X|Y|REL|USRN|SAON|PAON|PAONB|STREETf|LOCAL|TOWN
4534|Y      |X| |2  |1123|1   |yes |no   |NO NAME|CHORL|CHORL
3456|N      | |Y|2  |1445|3   |no  |no   |NO NAME|LANCS|LANCS
3457|Y      |X|Y|1  |1456|44  |no  |no   |NO NAME|MANCS|BIRMI
```

How would I go about blanking the $10 out and then blanking $11 out if its the same as $12

Thanks in advance

So far I have:

```
BEGIN{

FS= "|"

}

{

if($10 == "NO NAME" && $11==$12){
    $10=="";
    $11=="";
   }


print $0 > "testing.txt";

}
End
```

Comment: `Basicall this is what I need to do in awk`.  Ok.  But what did you try?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest to use the `-F '|'` flag to set the field separator to the pipe symbol (the vertical line). After that, the logic seems straight forward.

Comment: Thats what I have above but nothing prints out. New to awk

Comment: Read your posted input and your posted script. Do you see any lines in your posted input where `$10 == "No Name"` as your script is testing for? Think about it a bit and update your question.

Comment: Oh yes changed that, thanks Ed!!. Still not printing out what I want though!  TIA Amy

Comment: @AmyC, redirect output to testing.txt after **awk 'command' filename** i.e. `awk command filename>testing.txt`

Comment: its just outputs an empty file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}$10=="NO NAME" && $11==$12{$10=""; $11="";}{print $0}'  
filename>testing.txt
```

Comment: Ths will replaces all `|`s with spaces and will erase $10 and $11 if $10 contains the text "SUENO NAMELESS" or various other strings and $11 contains `THE` while $12 contains `FATHER` or various other strings.

Comment: @EdMorton yes changed as far removal of `|` is concerned

Comment: @user1502952 I think we ended up having the same answer :)